# SpringBoot Autowiring a generic type fails because of multiple possible beans

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired

I'm trying to create a class that Autowire an object of type T.

```
@component    
public class TaskScheduler<T extends TaskService>{
    @Autowired
    private T taskService;
}
```

the problem is that I have two components that extend `TaskService`.

```
@component
public class firstTaskService extends TaskService {

}
```

and

```
@component
public class secondTaskService extends TaskService {

}
```

so when this line is executed (`ts` is being created)

```
@Autowired
TaskScheduler<firstTaskService> ts;
```

I get this error :

> **Description:**
>   Parameter 1 of constructor in TaskScheduler required a single bean, but 2 were found

the message I got suggested this :

> **Action:** Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify
>   the bean that should be consumed.

But from what I understood, the `@Primary` and `@Qualifier` annotations make me choose 1 of the components, which not what I want because I want to use `firstTaskService` and `secondTaskService` with that same class (`TaskScheduler`).

How could this be done?

**Edit:** Clarification: My objective is to reuse the `TaskScheduler` class with different classes that extend the `TaskService` class (not to use multiple classes that extend `TaskService` together in `TaskScheduler`).

Comment: This is an interesting question. I'm not an expert at either generics or spring autowiring, but I think I know what'w going on. generics are just syntactic sugar to help the compiler to know what to do. that sugar is stripped away in the final binaries. So afer compilation, all TaskScheduler objects look the same and have just a "private List taskService" member in them. Since spring comes long later at runtime to do the autowiring, it doesn't know what to do because it doesn't see any of the generics information that was stripped away. - in short, I fear that this just can't work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to autowire all beans that extends `TaskService` maybe you should change the autowired field to a `List`:

```
@Component    
public class TaskScheduler<T extends TaskService>{
    @Autowired
    private List<T> taskService;
}
```

In this way Spring should put in the `List` all autowireable beans that extends `TaskService`.

**EDIT**: since you want to dinamically select the type of `TaskService` the only way I've found is the following. First, redefine your `TaskScheduler`:

```
public class TaskScheduler <T extends TaskService>{

    private T taskService;

    public void setTaskService(T taskService) {
        this.taskService = taskService;
    }
}
```

Your `TaskService` and related subclasses should remain untouched. Set up a configuration class as it follows:

```
@Configuration
public class TaskConf {

    @Autowired
    private FirstTaskService firstTaskService;

    @Autowired
    private SecondTaskService secondTaskService;

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler<FirstTaskService> firstTaskServiceTaskScheduler(){
        TaskScheduler<FirstTaskService> t =  new TaskScheduler<>();
        t.setTaskService(firstTaskService);
        return t;
    }

    @Bean
    public TaskScheduler<SecondTaskService> secondTaskServiceTaskScheduler(){
        TaskScheduler<SecondTaskService> t =  new TaskScheduler<>();
        t.setTaskService(secondTaskService);
        return t;
    }

}
```

And then test your `TaskScheduler` in this way:

```
@Autowired
TaskScheduler<firstTaskService> ts;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, sorry if my question isn't clear but I don't want all the beans to be autowired, I  want to create a TaskScheduler with firstTaskService and another scheduler somewhere else with secondTaskService. I want to reuse the TaskScheduler with different TaskService beans.

Comment: thaks again, I need to try this later, I'll comment what will happen.