# Spring: Trouble Autowiring services implementing a base interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I am bit puzzled by the way spring instantiates and Autowires the services.

Basically, I am looking to find a solution to the below problem which is blocking my app to start.

```
Field titleService1 in com.scorpio.spring.security.oauth2.controller.TitleController required a single bean, but 2 were found:
    - genderServiceImpl: defined in file [\spring\authorities\target\classes\com\spring\security\service\GenderServiceImpl.class]
    - titleServiceImpl: defined in file [\spring\authorities\target\classes\com\spring\security\service\TitleServiceImpl.class]
```

I have two Rest controllers namely `TitleController` and `CompanyController` with each controller referencing one or multiple services. The services are the implementation of `BaseService<T>`

**TitleController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/secured/title")
public class TitleController {

    @Autowired
    private BaseService<Title> titleService;

}
```

**CompanyController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/secured/company")
public class CompanyController {

    @Autowired
    private BaseService<Title> titleService;

    @Autowired
    private BaseService<Gender> genderService;
}
```

**BaseService.java**

```
public interface BaseService<T> {

    T get(Integer id);

    T get(String t);

    List<T> getAll();

    void create(T t);

    T update(T t);

    void delete(Integer id);

    void delete(T t);
}
```

Looking at the error `required a single bean, but 2 were found` and since there are two different implementation of `BaseService`, I do understand that Spring is unable to decide which Bean to `Autowire` as none of the implementation is annotated with `@Qualifer`, `@Primary` etc.

But what is more confusing is that, when I comment out the `titleService` from `TitleController` and re run my app, it just works. My question is how spring is able to Autowire the appropriate services in `CompanyController` and why if I try to Autowire in `TitleController`, it doesn't work ?

Many thanks.

Comment: What version of Spring are you using?

Comment: @Jay It's `5.0.2`

Comment: What happens if you inject via the Constructor instead of using field level?

Comment: @Jay Didn't make any difference, I am still getting the same error.

Comment: When you comment out. Does the ```CompanyController``` work? I mean HTTP endpoint.

Comment: @MichałMielec Yes, it does.

Comment: Spring should understand generics. It was introduced here https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/03/spring-framework-4-0-and-java-generics. But the mystery in that case is why single injection does not work :/

Comment: Looks like the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54790110/springboot-autowiring-a-generic-type-fails-because-of-multiple-possible-beans/54790427#54790427

Comment: @Nishant could you also add to your question which version of java and spring-core are you using. Do you use spring-boot-maven-plugin?

Comment: @Michal Java version is ‘8’ and Spring core is ‘5.0.2’. I do use spring boot maven plugin but I am currently running this from eclipse.

Comment: @MichałMielec I have now few more classes implementing BaseService and from what I can see, everything works as long as you just have a single instance of all the implementation Autowired and the moment you try to Autowire another instance of the same service, Spring starts throwing the same error again.

Answer (score -2):

Use qualifier annotation along with autowired. Qualifier is used to specify which implementation of interface to use.

```html
@Autowired
@Qualifier("Audi")
private Car car;
```